# How to declare the output type of a GNU Radio block to be PMT?

Tags: python, numpy, gnuradio

Short: I want to output PMTs in my block, but GNU Radio won't let me.

Generally I write OOT blocks for different applications on GNU Radio. Here I am trying to write a block for outputting a file as a message type.

The thing is if the output of our block if of type `numpy.float32`, we declare the same using:

```
def __init__(self):
  gr.sync_block.__init__(self,name="<anything_you_want>",out_sig=[(numpy.float32)])
```

Now I have a similar problem where I want the output to be of type PMT of GNU Radio. What should `out_sig` be in that case?

Comment: Which admins do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PMT (polymorphic types) are variable sized, portable containers.

They are used for message passing and tags, but not for streaming data.

If you want to output a message, then defined an empty `out_sig`, i.e.

```
..., out_sig=[], in_sig=[])
```

and use the `message_port_register_out` method to register an output port, and the `message_port_pub` method to send a message.

Message passing is documented in [the doxygen documentation](https://gnuradio.org/doc/doxygen/page_msg_passing.html).

However, I'd recommend you take the [Guided Tutorials](https://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/Guided_Tutorials), and read chapters 1-5, which explain the difference between item streams and messages. Since you can already write OOTs, this should be a quick read for you :)

If you want a minimal block that already uses the aforementioned methods, try my minimal [`variable_to_msg`](https://github.com/marcusmueller/gr-msgtools/blob/master/python/variable_to_msg.py) block.

Also, there's already a block that opens a file, and extracts messages: It's part of Tim O'Shea's [`gr-pyqt`](https://github.com/osh/gr-pyqt), and is called [`file_message_source`](https://github.com/osh/gr-pyqt/blob/master/python/file_message_source.py).